# Wrapping object is affecting other meshes

Tags: mesh

I set an object to wrap another object, which is working fine. But when I go to add another mesh, it affects that mesh as well. How do I "turn off" wrapping of other objects?[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it's a new object and not a new mesh in the same object?

Comment: As @moonboots asks, did you add your new object in Edit or Object mode? If it was in Edit mode, it's actually a part of your original mesh.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the "snap during transformation" set to "on".
Thank you for helping me check off some things. Th[image]at was frustrating.